# Редирект, которого нет

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, браузер, редирект

Здравствуйте.

Возникла уже не первый раз подобная ситуация: на сайте был редирект, допустим, такой:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://название_сайта.ru/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Но штука такая, что редирект этот был на сайте под адресом 
[http://поддомен.название_сайта.ru](http://%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD.%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0.ru)

Как следствие, браузер меня перекидывал на основной. Но когда я этот редирект убрал - то тот-же браузер продолжает меня по этому редиректу кидать.
Это при том, что другие браузеры уже сайт на поддомене открывают корректно.
Удаление истории и др. не помогает. При чем проблема на chrome, firefox, opera, safary. Т.е. не имеет значения, че это за браузер.

Получается, что факт редиректа где-то на компе у браузера сохраняется и продолжает срабатывать. Проблема как на OS X El Capitan, так и на Windows 10.

Может быть кто-то знает, в чем проблема может быть? Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему?

Comment: Попробуйте на том же браузере что вызывает редирект, запустить в инкогнито, если перекидывать перестает, то вы не правильно чистите кэш браузера.

Comment: Понял, разобрался, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо пользователю [Vasiliy Rusin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183429/vasiliy-rusin) за ответ.
Сам ответ: Попробуйте на том же браузере что вызывает редирект, запустить в инкогнито, если перекидывать перестает, то вы не правильно чистите кэш браузера.